# Cannot split .ape file with flacon

Tags: lubuntu, conversion, flac

I have CDImage.ape and CDImage.cue files that I want to convert to separate FLAC files using flacon.

Converting first with ffmpeg the .ape file to .flac and then splitting it with flacon and the same .cue file works like a charm! But if I use flacon directly on the .ape it fails with corresponding error:

[image: flacon fails to handle single ape file]

the cue file reads something like:

```
REM GENRE Funk
REM DATE 1970
REM DISCID SomeID
REM COMMENT "ExactAudioCopy v0.99pb3"
PERFORMER "SomeArtist"
TITLE "SomeTitle"
FILE "CDImage.ape" WAVE
  TRACK 01 AUDIO
    TITLE "track01"
    PERFORMER "SomeArtist"
    INDEX 01 00:00:00
  TRACK 02 AUDIO
    TITLE "track02"
    PERFORMER "SomeArtist"
    INDEX 00 10:04:49
    INDEX 01 10:07:22
  TRACK 03 AUDIO
    TITLE "track03"
    PERFORMER "SomeArtist"
    INDEX 00 15:28:54
    INDEX 01 15:31:09
  TRACK 04 AUDIO
    TITLE "track04"
    PERFORMER "SomeArtist"
    INDEX 00 18:46:21
    INDEX 01 18:48:05
  TRACK 05 AUDIO
    TITLE "track05"
    PERFORMER "SomeArtist"
    INDEX 00 24:47:17
    INDEX 01 24:49:45
  TRACK 06 AUDIO
    TITLE "track06"
    PERFORMER "SomeArtist"
    INDEX 00 27:45:56
    INDEX 01 27:48:50
  TRACK 07 AUDIO
    TITLE "track07"
    PERFORMER "SomeArtist"
    INDEX 00 31:20:05
    INDEX 01 31:24:33
  TRACK 08 AUDIO
    TITLE "track08"
    PERFORMER "SomeArtist"
    INDEX 00 34:46:57
    INDEX 01 34:47:47
  TRACK 09 AUDIO
    TITLE "track09"
    PERFORMER "SomeArtist"
    INDEX 00 35:43:06
    INDEX 01 35:44:29
  TRACK 10 AUDIO
    TITLE "track10"
    PERFORMER "SomeArtist"
    INDEX 00 38:35:22
    INDEX 01 38:37:14
```

I suspect there is some ape codec missing but then mac seems correctly installed and linked to flacon (I believe this package contains the ape codec)

[image: Flacon settings]

Thanks for your help

Comment: I created an ape cd rip with cue (using abcde) and this worked perfectly with flacon to flac. So something wrong with your rip or the applications you are using? I used flacon 3.1.1 (although I see new version out now) and mac 4.11. Is this similar to your versions?

Comment: Well a simple mac "CDImage.ape" -v gives me --- Monkey's Audio Console Front End (v 3.99) (c) Matthew T. Ashland --- Verifying... Error: 1009 so I guess file is broken

Comment: I suspect so as well, running the same command on my own cd rip gives the following: https://pastebin.com/L846tsri